# Чат в реальном времени

Tags: php

Всем привет, хочу сделать чат в реальном времени, но не знаю, как и с помощью какой технологии. Пока сделал на php так: имею 2 файла, messlist.php и messadd.php, и на странице index.php они в iframe подгружаются. Но чтобы увидеть новые сообщения надо подождать даже те же 5 сек, чтобы обновилось. А как сделать в реальном времени, т.е. отправил, и сразу же появилось?

Comment: Ajax это то что Вам нужно

Comment: А он тяжелый для изучения?

Comment: PHP- это не то, что Вам нужно (хотя если демоном запустить, то сойдет).  
Long pooling, websocket- то что нужно.

Comment: Там нечего изучать, посылаете get запрос пишите функцию которая срабатывает когда приходит ответ(или не приходит если сервер в дауне)

Comment: "как сделать в реальном времени т.е отправил и **сразу же** появилось", какой ajax??? Упоротые?

Comment: А вообще - @Csharp такую задачу, как раз таки, лучше решать на @Csharp, а не на PHP :)

Comment: Да на логин не обращайте внимания, C# для меня пока не основной язык)) Хочу web знать!

Comment: @Csharp - одно другому не мешает, к тому-же фраза "Хочу web знать" как-бы намекает на то, что вам нужно начать с основ и только после определятся с выбором языка и технологий

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте, тут одним php не обойтись, Вам нужен ajax.
Вот набросал функцию на php, как создает блок, который обновляется, без перезагрузки

```
$num = 'n'; // Чтобы название функции не повторялась
function ajax($file,$time=7){ // $file - Файл какой надо загружать, $time - интервал в секундах обновления
    global $num;
    return '<div id="'.$num.'">
    <div class="loadup" style="text-align:center;">Загрузка...</div>
</div>
<script>
    function show_'.$num.'(){$.ajax({url: "'.$file.'", cache: true, success: function(html) { $("#'.$num.'").html(html); }});}$(document).each(function(){show_'.$num.'(); setInterval(show_'.$num.', '.$time.'000);});
</script>';
    $num.=$num;
}
```

Насчет использование $num - без комментариев =).
Использование функции: Выбираем размещение на страничке, пишем функцию ajax('имя файла, какой отвечает за чат', интервал обновление контента), пример ajax('chat/index.php',3)

Comment: @Node_pro - вы правы, комментарии тут излишни, только вот $num тут занимает далеко не первое место

Comment: Пытался облегчить Автору задачу. Если есть ошибка или улучшить код, чтобы его не усложнять, рад буду выслушать, может где-то сделан просчет =)

Comment: @Node_pro - не нужно никому ничего облегчать, да, возможно, все будет работать, но ни ума ни понимания у автора не добавится, к тому-же работать с таким ...ом, мягко говоря, не приятно, а если его много и вовсе - невозможно.

Как по мне очевидно то, что автор, просто напросто, пришел к изучении JS, от него не убежать :)

Comment: Я старался помочь, может мой пример понятнее(легче) для реализации будет =))).

Comment: @Csharp, @Node_pro... и все говорят о `php`...

Answer (score 3):

Технология - [Comet](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet)

Answer (score 2):

[Создаем чат на Node.js и](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127525/) [Socket.IO](http://Socket.IO) - изучайте.

> В данной статье я попытаюсь показать,
> как можно создать простой чат,
> используя Node.js в связке с
> [Socket.IO](http://Socket.IO). Изначально я хотел
> построить чат на чистых Websockets, но
> столкнулся с практически полным
> отсутствием готовых реализаций сервера
> для них в Интернете. Так что решил не
> изобретать велосипед, а использовать
> готовую библиотеку.  В моем случае
> сервер работает под Ubuntu, поэтому
> все примеры будут для неё (и ссылки в
> примерах — на него же).